# Any Airflow configuration that will make new DAGS dropped in ./dags folder show up in the UI more quickly?

Tags: docker, airflow

I'm trying to learn a little Airflow by running the official airflow docker compose image
[ per instructions here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.1/start/docker.html ].
I was able to launch all the services such that when I dropped my test DAG in the ./dags
folder I eventually saw my DAG in the UI and could run it.

But this took several minutes.  And continues to take several minutes every time I 'deploy' a new dag into ./dags.

I'm wondering if there is some configuration option that would cause the scanning of the
./dags folder to happen faster so I don't have to wait around as much.    Thanks in advance !

Comment: may I ask how many DAGs are you trying to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In airflow.cfg file you may want to change this, default is 5 minutes.

```
dag_dir_list_interval = 300
```

After changing the value, just restart webserver, scheduler, triggerer, worker docker containers i.e. without killing them or doing docker-compose down. e.g.

```
docker restart your_airflow_webserver_container_id
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are several reasons for slowness of your DAG's loading.

1. If you have a lot (thousands) of DAGs ([dynamic DAGs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/dynamic-dag-generation.html#dynamic-dag-generation) are slower, depends on how you generate them).
2. Your DAG is too complex - see [Reducing DAG complexity](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#reducing-dag-complexity).
3. You can test your code speed - [DAG Loader Test](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#dag-loader-test)